# Just upgraded to 11.10 - How do I disable Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Forgot about unity. Apparently not as easy to disable as last time.